# How to catch if the user click on 'Yes' button with jquery Dialog plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, alert

I am trying to use the following plugin to display a message stating 'Are you sure....?' then if the user click on Yes then submit a form.

http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/

I have create the button and the alert message. I do get the message display on the screen but when the user click 'Yes' button nothing happens! What am I doing wrong?

I have followed the second example in the previous link.

Here is what I have so far

```
<div class="mirrorSubmit" id="updateData" >Update</div>


$('#updateData').easyconfirm({locale: { title: 'Are you sure?', button: ['No','Yes']}});

$('#updateData').click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('yes');
    var formData = $('#wholeForm').serialize();
    submitForm(formData);   
});
```

I do not get any errors but I don't get any action.

console.log does not log yes so it making me sure that it is not detecting the Yes click.

Thanks for your help